# MYSQL Query to INSERT INTO a value into one row and copy data from another table into another row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need something like this

```
INSERT INTO `tb1`(`button`,'name')
SELECT button FROM `tb2` WHERE `ID` = 1, VALUE ('some name')
```

In button I want to copy button data from tb2, In name I just want to put in a name.  I can either copy from another table or enter a VALUE but I cannot do both.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This syntax is not supported. Answer @GurV posted does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `tb1`(`button`,`name`)
SELECT button, 'Some name' FROM `tb2` WHERE `ID` = 1
```